# What is the purpose of the <div id="Circle"> on this website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On this website http://science-inc.com/ (on the index.html),
what is the purpose of div#Circle?

```
<div id="left-section">
    <h1>Science</h1>
    <canvas width="1278" height="614"></canvas>
    <div id="Circle"></div>
</div>
```

It is an empty element. It has :before and :after pseudo elements, but they don’t seem to be doing anything.

[image: Screenshot of Inspect Element on Science Inc]

Comment: You've pretty much answered your question. There is no JavaScript or CSS interacting with the circle on the client side. It is literally useless.

Comment: Why do you ask? Just idle curiosity or what?

Comment: It's very possible it used to do something but they removed the functionality but not the element.

Comment: If you go to `::before` and `::after` style of that div and you check/uncheck de `position` property you'll see a `science` appears over the image. Like you were told already, they probably tried to use it to show the red circle with the text and they didn't remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just a blank `<div>` that's making no effect on the view of page because it has height 0 (because it has no content), width same as it's parent element and no other staying.so there is no mean of it.

[image]